# jQuery function that call controller method from client side every 10 seconds mvc razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got a problem that i cannot solve cause of my incomplete knowledge of jQuery/Java syntax but which problem can be fast solved by someone with more experience than me.

I want to build a simple script to run on client side that will call a controller method every 10 seconds (method is responsible for receive data from message server)

all i do so far is search web and more i read more i get confused..

basic need are

- use jQuery ( there was a tip that says it is best choice)
- call method every 10 seconds

method i want to call is: "callGetMessagesFromClientSide" and it's in CoordinatorsController

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var callETs = setInterval(function () { callMessages() }, 10000);

    function callMessages()
    {
         var url = @Url.Action("callGetMessagesFromClientSide", "Coordinators")
         $.get(url);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap generated URL in quotes.

*Use*

```
var url = '@Url.Action("callGetMessagesFromClientSide", "Coordinators")';
```

*instead of*

```
var url = @Url.Action("callGetMessagesFromClientSide", "Coordinators")
```

Rest of your code should work.

```
function callMessages() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("callGetMessagesFromClientSide", "Coordinators")';
    $.get(url, function(response) {
       //Perform some operation in the callback if require 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank's now it's working, shame that i did not ask earlier i would save some time...

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there, try this:

```
function callMessages()
{
     var url = '@Url.Action("callGetMessagesFromClientSide", "Coordinators")';
     var update = $.get(url);
     update.done(function(response) {
         //handle server response
     });
}
```

depending on what the server returns (e.g. JSON, HTML etc) depends on how you handle it